# Using cookies to store oauth authorization tokens

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, instagram-api

I’ve seen a couple examples of this ( Storing auth tokens in a cookie )already; but I’d like to understand the reason for doing this.I think this would create more problems because you have to specifically remember to delete the cookie after you’re finished. For my specific example ; I am dealing with Instagram via the API 
Thank you for any and all help

Answer (score 0):

I`m not sure exactly what you're asking for. You need to know how to store the token? However, then is no need to remember to delete a cookie, just set an expiration date.

Regarding the API, you will need a valid token everytime you do a request to API, so don`t delete it, otherwise you will need to re-authenticate everytime.

Note: For Instagram Business Accounts you need to use Facebook API. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-api/v2.10

Comment: Yeah I thought that that cookies weren’t relevant for api scripts Then I saw a comment from somebody saying to remember to delete all cookies You may have created after you’re done. That’s what got me confused